# Z-index problem when dealing with clip-path objects

Tags: html, css, z-index, clip-path

I'm having some problems I'm trying to have two clip path polygons overlap each other when hovered over by the mouse, I'm using z-index's and trying to change them depending on with overlay is being hovered over but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
.banner {
    bottom 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
}

.overlayleft {
    position absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom 0;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlayright {
    position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    bottom: 0;
    top 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 25% 100%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlayright:hover{
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.overlayleft:hover{
  width: 100%;
}




</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="banner">
<div class="overlayright"></div>
<div class="overlayleft"></div>
    
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need z-index values inside the :hover rulesets in order to make them respond when you hover with your mouse. Whatever z-index values you have in the non-:hover rulesets are the default, and then when hovered over, those values override whatever values were in the preceding applicable rulesets.

This should help, assuming you want to bring the overlay forward in the stack. Adjust the value of z-index as needed to bring it back or forward:

```
.overlayright:hover{
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.overlayleft:hover{
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems that overlayleft still remains on top

Comment: Did you try removing the z-index from the non-:hover rulesets?

Comment: Yeah no change.